# jQuery and Raphael within JS-"Classes"

Tags: jquery, raphael, program-entry-point

I´m seriously having trouble just getting a simple canvas within my main-class to work although the plain main-code worked in other projects - it´s just the Raphael-part that is replacing the former code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){  new Main(); } );
$.Class

("Main",
 {
  init:
    function()
    { // Initialize the canvas.
      var paper = Raphael("canvas",800,500);
      paper.circle( 100, 100, 50);
    },

 });
```

Without the main-"frame" everything´s fine, of course... now really have no clue anymore what might be wrong in the constellation ...

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Do you have a link to the `$.Class` plugin?

Comment: *facepalm* ... you are right ... I just copied the jquery-library ... thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest likelihood is that you don't have an element with an id of "canvas" anywhere on the page. We don't know how the $.Class works, but in general it's really worth the time to learn a bit about how closures work in JS instead of trying to treat it as a classically OOP language. This will do the trick (again, assuming "" is in there somewhere):

```
$(document).ready( function(){  main(); } );

function main () {
    var paper = Raphael("canvas",800,500);
    paper.circle(100, 100, 50);
    return {
        get_paper: function () {
            return paper;    
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: The "canvas" element is located in the html-file. Thank you very much, it worked ... but why do you have to return the paper specifically, while otherwise you do not have to do this?

Comment: You don't have to -- in fact, it's useless if you don't set main() equal to something. The idea is that you treat each invocation of main() like an instance of a class and return the methods you may want to use later, since you can no longer access "paper" directly. It exists in a closure, like a private property in a traditional OOP language. I highly recommend Crockford's "Javascript: The Good Parts."